# Display issue: Vertically center in line when using linespace 20

Tags: vimrc, macvim

I have

`set linespace 20`

in my .vimrc and I quite like the clarity it provides. The only issue I see right now is:

[image]

Notice how the spacing at the top end of the line is more than the bottom end of the line? How do I make it so that the text in the line is vertically center aligned?

Comment: i doubt, you can adjust that in Vim.

Comment: @shashanka did you manage to get that fixed?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco No...